# How to export cpu usage from time profiler instrument

Tags: xcode7, cpu, instruments

I am profiling cpu usage using time profiler in instrument. Here I can get a graph regarding to cpu usage and recording time. When I choose "export track" it exports all the call tree instead of the graph. I am wondering is there a way I can export this graph (i.e., time and cpu usage at that time).

If not, is there any way I can get time-cpu value? Or average cpu usage in a time interval?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just click save button or use cmd+s to save file, you will get the .trace file. Double click the trace file to open the file with instrument and you will get all the recorded data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. In instrument, I can see the trace data. However, I want to export each value at each timestamp to a .txt or other format that I can further analyze instead of visually presenting it as in the instrument. Any idea?

Comment: Hey @ZigZagZebra, just wondering if you've found the solution for this yet?